# BigQuery Cannot Modify Partitioned Table Schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Per the BigQuery documentation I am attempting to modify a table's schema by adding a field. The table in question is a partition slice (partitioned by day). I am planning on performing the action on every slice.

Per the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables), I should be able to add field to a partitioned table like any other table. However whenever I attempt to add a field to a partitioned table, I am met with this error:

```
Could not edit table schema.: Cannot change partitioned/clustered table to non partitioned/clustered table.
```

I am not able to find any good information on what this error means, or what I'm doing wrong. I have successfully added a field to a non-partitioned table. Does the community have any good ideas to help me troubleshoot?

Comment: "However whenever I attempt to add a field to a partitioned table" - can you describe how was this attempt attempted?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa either using the API (connected via Ruby/Python) or via the UI

Comment: Unless you're using the patch API, you would need to specify the partitioning spec too, otherwise the server would think you want to remove the partitioning spec.

Comment: when you say "using the API" - can you post the code used?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using the `update_table` method to [update the schema in python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#manually_adding_an_empty_column), correct me if I'm wrong. You have to do it with the patch API you can [try this API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch) to have a better view on how to do it.